# PC not booting from Ubuntu live dvd

Tags: boot, windows-xp

So finally I can enter my BIOS! So, I decided to boot through Ubuntu today and went into bios. I changed my boot device to CD/DVD, saved the settings (F10) and then it restarted or something. But, then it didn't boot through Ubuntu but it booted xp. I tried it 3 times and all the times it booted xp. Then i changed the boot setting. And the it booted neither xp nor ubuntu. I get this error:

"Reboot and select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot media in selected Boot device and press a key_" (without the quotation marks)

What could be the problem? I tried Using another dvd. There is same problem with it! What should I do? For more see this: (important if you need to understand more) http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/104137-pc-not-booting-from-dvd/#entry1392823

Thanks :)

Comment: Make sure the first boot device is your hard disk then XP must open.

Comment: I don't need XP. I need Ubuntu!

Comment: make sure first boot device is DVD or you can also try from pen drive. It should work.

Comment: It's the DVD. But still the same happens :(

Answer (score 0):

Try going into "select boot device" instead of BIOS. It should be F5, F8 or F12 (it depends on the manufacturer)

If you can see the CD/DVD device among the options, then it must be something wrong with your DVD (e.a. it's not bootable, or some files are corrupt)

If you don't see the CD/DVD device, check your cables or maybe switch SATA or IDE slots on motherboard...

Comment: I have a MSIG31TM-P21 motherboard. Does it have select to boot option?

Comment: It should be F11 for boot menu for that motherboard.